# How to exclude domains in the Houndify API?

Tags: houndify

How can i exclude Domains in the Houndify API?
In the [RequestInfoJSON documentation](https://docs.houndify.com/reference/RequestInfo) is a field called domains to "omit some domains when doing a request". However there is no format specified.

By analysing the SDK i discover the following structure:

```
"Domains": {
   "Exclude": {
      "DomainNames": ["weather"]
   }
}
```

However, no matter which domain name i put into the array the domain will be executed. (By using the "only" functionality i got a NoResultCommand.) Disabling the domains in the dashboard is no option for me.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://docs.houndify.com/reference/Domains) is the doc explaining "Domains" parameter.

Specifying following value to "Domains" parameter as part of request header in API tester seems to have successfully suppressed "Wikipedia" domain to be invoked:

```
{"Exclude": {"DomainNames": ["Wikipedia"]}}
```

Comment: Thank you!
I also noticed that the name is case sensitiv and while my code was working, the server switched to a fallback weather domain. So the result contend was the same and not as i expected. Additionally excluding the fallback domain gives the expected result.